# Dyanamic Array Class, Program runs well but with Error

Tags: c++

This is my Code

```
#ifndef INTLIST_H_INCLUDED
#define INTLIST_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class intList
{
    int upper_bound;
    int arr[0];
    public:
        intList(){ arr[0] = 0; upper_bound = 0; }
        void append(int x);
        void sort();
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, intList&);
        inline int len(){ return upper_bound; }
        inline int &operator [](int x){ return arr[x]; }
    private:
        void increment(int *a, int &l);
        void swap(int &a, int &b);
};

void intList::swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void intList::increment(int *a, int &b)
{
    b++;
    a[b] = 0;
}

void intList::append(int num)
{
    arr[upper_bound] = num;
    increment(arr, upper_bound);
}

void intList::sort()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < upper_bound; i++)
    {
        int minLoc = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j<upper_bound; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] < arr[minLoc])
                minLoc = j;
        }
        if(minLoc != i)
            swap(arr[i], arr[minLoc]);
    }
}

ostream& operator << (ostream & dout, intList &a)
{
    dout << "[ ";
    for(int i = 0; i<a.upper_bound-1; i++)
        dout << a.arr[i] << ", ";
    dout << a.arr[a.upper_bound-1] << " ]";

    return dout;
}

#endif // INTLIST_H_INCLUDED
```

The Code does its work perfectly fine. But at the end the Program Crashes. Giving some error like 
process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) execution time : some seconds.

Just didn't get where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

For example, you have a fixed array of 0 size. If you want a **dynamically** growable array, you can use `std::vector`: you can add new items at the end of the vector (dynamically resizing it) using `push_back()` method:

```
#include <vector>

// Start with an empty vector
std::vector<int> v;

// Add some items to it
v.push_back(10);
v.push_back(20);
....
```

Note also that in header files it's not good to insert a `using namespace std;`. In this way you pollute the global namespace with STL classes, which is bad. Just **use `std::` prefix in header files**.

Moreover, if you want to print the class content to an output stream, you may want to take the class as a **const reference**, since instances of the class are input parameters (you *observe* them and print their content to the stream):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const IntList& a)
{
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks bad:

```
int arr[0];
```

First, C++ doesn't allow zero-sized fixed size arrays. Second, your code certainly needs more than a zero sized array.

Whatever use you make of this code is undefined behaviour (UB). UB includes code seemingly "working perfectly fine".

Comment: I think I am getting it. Probably its like that arrays are given sequential space in memory location. Here I am not declaring exactly how much space would be needed. And there comes time when the connected memory location might not be empty and there the program shows error.

Comment: @tehTerminator right, you are reading and writing beyond the array's bounds, to places you shouldn't.

Comment: @tehTerminator BTW are you trying to implement a dynamic sized array as an exercise? If so, then using `std::vector` under the hood is not really a solution.

Comment: Then what should I try. The Book I have doesn't have anything about Vectors. I though May be I could create some thing like the code above.

Comment: @tehTerminator I don't know what "the book" is, but what I wanted to say is, if you are doing an excercise, and the goal is to implement a dynamic size array, then using a vector would be kind of cheating, because it is a professionally desinged and implemented dynamic sized array class. On the other hand, if you just need the thing for something else, then just use vector.